# How to get a full items in a wordpress feed?

Tags: wordpress, rss, feed

I'm developping a mobile application that need feed of all posts from my wordpress website,

in the website the posts are grouped by categories, so i get the full feed or the feed by category with these links:

```
example.com/feed
example.com/category/categoryName/feed
```

The issue is the urls returned just 10 items (posts)

is there a way to return the full posts in the feed ?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can always change your feed numbers in `Settings -> Reading`, but I'd advise against that. If you're building a mobile app, the RSS feed may not be the wisest way to go (as it wasn't build with that intent). I'd suggest using something as the [WP API](http://wp-api.org/), or the [JSON API](https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/) plugin. You have much better control over your requests, and the responses are cleaner, too, they're not that big ass XML file.

If you *really* want to change the feed, I guess this snippet might help:

```
if (isset ($query->query_vars['feed']) and ($query->query_vars['feed'] == 'ics')) 
    add_filter('post_limits','__return_empty_string');
```

But then again, I don't think this is a good idea. There's a nice topic about this [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4736/get-all-posts-in-rss).